# The accuracy & malleability of memory for color

Tags: perception, memory, vision, color

**How accurate is colour memory for the standard person?**

It would seem most people are quite good at remembering the colour of objects by visualising the object. But in some cases peoples visualisation could be wrong. This is the case I am interested in.

**Can this visualised 'incorrect' colour be shifted in a specific way?**

Is there any known reason why someone would visualise objects colour incorrectly in some set shifted way. E.g. They always remember things by their composite colour?

---

**Motivation:**

My memory self ranked:

- Faces - Great
- Names - Average
- Geography - Poor
- Colour - Non-existent

For some reason, I find myself incapable of remembering colours unless I specially label it with a colour, and often people will ask me to get something of theirs without telling me the colour, and I will be unable to find it because I can visualise it perfectly in the **wrong** colour.

One example I can remember. A large brick wall on my drive, I can perfectly remember(still can) that it was a light lime green, roughly [this colour](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=lime%20green&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=wagYH4e4E8FMzM%253A%253B-cZGmOUsO1ZgJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fcolors.findthebest.com%25252Fl%25252F433%25252FLime-Green&source=iu&pf=m&fir=wagYH4e4E8FMzM%253A%252C-cZGmOUsO1ZgJM%252C_&usg=__BFDsyiOl_ZsOfxhqpT_aH4HQybI%3D&biw=1920&bih=955&ved=0CCoQyjc&ei=-p95VNnhA4rj8AXGQw), and I was thinking about it in the car as I was planning my route mentally. Once I reached it I saw that it was purple, my girlfriend tells me essentially [this colour](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=purple&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=N6B5VKDaFYnn8gX_s4LQBQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=955#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=CpekwSgVZFfjFM%253A%3BcEg2mIQqtTJ2yM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblogs.independent.co.uk%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F04%252Fcolor-purple1.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblogs.independent.co.uk%252F2011%252F04%252F19%252Fpurple-prose%252F%3B499%3B499).

Comment: I have removed the final portion (which was my sticking point with the self-help aspect of the question) and voted to reopen.  If you are concerned about how this neurological difference pertains to you, it's best to ask a clinician about it.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington Thank you :). When I said significance, I meant, 'is this a specific shift, say I am remembering in certain wave lengths' or something, not that I am medically concerned.

Comment: It was hard to tell that from the phrasing, but your first paragraph clarified all of that anyway.  Feel free to add in additional information.  We're not out to be draconian, the close reason is necessary to prevent a lot of "I have X, Y, Z symptoms, what's wrong with me?"-type questions, which this really wasn't at its core, anyway, but eliminating that ambiguity made it a stronger question.

Comment: I have edited the title to point more clearly to the central concern of the question; feel free to change it if you don't think it is accurate.

Comment: @Krysta Hey, always happy to get more attention on my post, thanks :).